# What are these things that surround museum exhibits called?

Tags: single-word-requests, image-identification

I'm trying to find the correct naming for these things in the image:

[image]

It's the things that surround the exhibits in a museum, and sometimes they delimit a walking area to guide visitors along. **I'm mostly interested when they define a route to follow.**

I'm thinking about red ribbons but I could only find an image with chains ('cause I don't know by what name to search them :D).

What's the whole ensemble called?

Comment: With "define a route to follow", do you refer more to (reconfigurable) arrangements such as in airport ceck-in queues?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: that could be an example, yes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A barrier to surround and protect something is called a **cordon**.  They can also be used to direct people to a destination.  (As in an airport queue or amusement park crowd management.)

Similarly the verb **to cordon off** means to enclose something with a barrier.

They're often made of velvet with hooks that allow them to be detached and reattached, hence the term **velvet rope**.  This style is most frequently used in theaters and nightclubs.  When something is felt to be exclusive or mysterious it's said to be:

> > Behind the [velvet rope.](https://glosbe.com/en/en/The%20Velvet%20Rope)

The posts used to hold up the cordon are called **stanchions**.

[image]

Comment: What about when they define a route, and not just blocking an entrance?

Comment: @Pips They're still cordons. They direct you by blocking access.

Comment: This doesn't include the posts, so it's not the whole setup.

Comment: @user47014 The posts are called stanchions.  And, the whole thing is called a cordon.  The rope portion is the part which the whole item takes its name from.

Comment: @David M Do you have a reference showing cordon is the whole thing? Because I see it defined as just the part that is stretched.

Comment: @user47014 It's a cordon.  That's what it's called.  You use it to cordon off a region.  Stanchions hold up a rope, chain, carved elephant tusks or the intestines of people.  It is immaterial what the stretched portion is made of.

Comment: @David M So you couldn't find a reference showing cordons include the posts? Because the OP was asking for the whole ensemble. I see definitions for cordon as just the rope or whatever hangs between the posts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98628/discussion-between-david-m-and-user47014).

Answer (score 4):

"***Queue bollards***" or "***rope bollards***" also come to mind. They can be used for the purpose of directing pedestrian foot traffic, controlling crowds and managing queues.

---

[image]

---

## Bollard

> > *chiefly British*: any of a series of short posts set at intervals to delimit an area (such as a traffic island) or to exclude vehicles.

Therefore, "***queue bollards***" or "***rope bollards***" are *bollards* with an ornamental cord or ribbon ([*cordon*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cordon)) that can be attached to or detached from them.

Comment: To clarify, AmE *dictionaries* conventionally define “bollard” in the narrow sense of a short post on a quay or the deck of a ship for attaching a ship's rope. But the sense of short, thick posts along a road to restrict access is in common use; see, for example, [“City Will Place 1,500 Bollards to Counter Vehicle Attacks”](https://nyti.ms/2EGaluA) (NY Times 20180102).

Answer (score 1):

They can be sold just as "Museum barriers".

"Use this ____ Museum Barrier with Dual Retractable Cords to queue and direct visitors through your exhibit space or encourage visitors to keep their distance from valuable artifacts. The two 7-foot elastic cords fully retract into the 39" high stanchion. This freestanding barrier's lower cord is 19.75" off the floor, making it ADA compliant. Add a freestanding receiver barrier or wall terminator (both sold separately) to end a line of barriers."

https://www.gaylord.com/Exhibit-%26-Display/Signage-%26-Traffic-Management/Traffic-Management/Q-Cord%26%23153%3B-Museum-Barrier-with-Dual-Retractable-Cords/p/HYB09347

There is also "Exhibition barrier systems" to surround single artifacts.

Comment: Maybe some think people who are in the business of making these things don't know what they are called?

Answer (score -2):

They are called [stanchions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stanchion).  This can refer to just the column, or a set of column and whichever material is used to connect them such as chains or velvet ropes.

> In event management a stanchion is an upright bar or post that includes retractable belts, velvet ropes, or plastic chains, sometimes in conjunction with wall-mounted barrier devices, barricades, and printed signage [...]

Comment: Stanchions are the columns only.  Not the ropes.

Comment: The first line of my linked wikipedia page disagrees with you.

Comment: I agree with @DavidM.  And the first line of your linked Wikipedia page *does not* disagree with David but disagrees with you, JRodge.  It, in fact, *does* agree with David.  It says, "A stanchion (/ˈstæntʃən/) is a sturdy upright fixture that provides support for some other object." The other object would be something like a chain or a velvet rope, as it goes on to explain.  While the term "velvet rope" can be construed as a barrier, a "stanchion," a singular pole that would hold a velvet rope, certainly would not.

Comment: @JRodge01 I had a look; the first line that comes up on my phone refers only to the upright. It might help for you to quote the relevant portion and include that in your answer.

Comment: Added the appropriate line.

Comment: If you're now pivoting to a definition of "stanchion" that also includes the portable kind that have retractable innards, that's clearly not what's depicted in the OP's question.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman those have a name, too. They're call TensaBarriers.

Comment: @DavidM TensaBarrier is a brand name, not the product name.